# passing a struct pointer to function give access violation

Tags: c++, struct

I am trying to pass a reference to a struct and a reference to a ifstream to a function. then it will populate the structs with what is in the file. if I take this out of the function and put it into main it all works. but now that I moved it to the function I am getting access violations.. I am still new to c++. so any help would be much appreciated..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


struct periodicElement
{
string code;
string name;
int number;
double weight;
};

void populateTable(periodicElement *aElement[], ifstream& inFile);

int main()
{
ifstream fileIn;    // Input file identifier    

const __int16 maxElements = 118;  

int elements = 0;

periodicElement atomic[maxElements];

periodicElement *ptr = & atomic[maxElements];

string line;

if (fileIn.fail())         // Test for file existence
{
    cout << "Problem opening file";
    exit(-1);
}

populateTable(atomic, fileIn);

    for (int i = 0; i < elements; i++)
{
    cout << atomic[i]->code << endl
    << atomic[i]->name << endl
    << atomic[i]->number << endl 
    << atomic[i]->weight << endl;
}

// Close file
fileIn.close();
system("pause");

return 0;
}

void populateTable(periodicElement *aElement[], ifstream& inFile)
{

int elements = 0;
while ((inFile >> aElement[elements]->code >> aElement[elements]->name >> aElement[elements]->number >> aElement[elements]->weight))
{
    elements += 1;
}

}
```

Comment: You are passing by pointer, not reference.  Passing by reference involves the '&' symbol such as `populateTable(std::vector<periodicElement>& vElement, ifstream& infile)`

Comment: `periodicElement` is an array of pointers. Those pointers don't point anywhere good.

Comment: You didn't do anything to update `elements` inside main, so your loop does nothing. The access violations are probably you having too many lines in your file, or something.